# I am facing End of file reached error

Tags: python-3.x

I am newbie to python and was trying following code

```
class Arm(object):
def __init__(self, SNo, ActivityDate, RequesterTeam, RequesterSignumId, RequesterEmailId,Circle,Customer,Technology,WOType,ProblemTitle,ActivityTypeorEqType,SiteID,BSCFACID,EngineerName,EngineerSignum,DetailDescriptionOfActivityToBePerformed,TimelineforActivityCompletion,WOIDbyWFM ):

    self.SNo= SNo
    self.ActivityDate=ActivityDate
    self.RequesterTeam=RequesterTeam
    self.RequesterSignumId=RequesterSignumId
    self.RequesterEmailId=RequesterEmailId
    self.Circle=Circle
    self.Customer=Customer
    self.Technology=Technology
    self.WOType=WOType
    self.ProblemTitle=ProblemTitle
    self.ActivityTypeorEqType=ActivityTypeorEqType
    self.SiteID=SiteID
    self.BSCFACID=BSCFACID
    self.EngineerName=EngineerName
    self.EngineerSignum=EngineerSignum
    self.DetailDescriptionOfActivityToBePerformed=DetailDescriptionOfActivityToBePerformed
    self.TimelineforActivityCompletion=TimelineforActivityCompletion
    self.WOIDbyWFM=WOIDbyWFM


def __str__(self):
    return("Arm object:\n"
        "SNo = {0}\n"
        "ActivityDate = {1}\n"
        "RequesterTeam = {2}\n"
        "RequesterSignumId = {3}\n"
        "RequesterEmailId = {4}\n"
        "Circle = {5}\n"
        "Customer = {6}\n"
        "Technology = {7}\n"
        "WOType = {8}\n"
        "ProblemTitle = {9}\n"
        "ActivityTypeorEqType = {10}\n"
        "SiteID = {11}\n"
        "BSCFACID = {12}\n"
        "EngineerName = {13}\n"
        "EngineerSignum = {14}\n"
        "DetailDescriptionOfActivityToBePerformed = {15}\n"
        "TimelineforActivityCompletion= {16}\n"
        "WOIDbyWFM = {17}\n"
        .format(self.SNo, 
                self.ActivityDate,
                self.RequesterTeam,
                self.RequesterSignumId,
                self.RequesterEmailId,
                self.Circle,
                self.Customer,
                self.Technology,
                self.WOType,
                self.ProblemTitle,
                self.ActivityTypeorEqType,
                self.SiteID,
                self.BSCFACID,
                self.EngineerName,
                self.EngineerSignum,
                self.DetailDescriptionOfActivityToBePerformed,
                self.TimelineforActivityCompletion,
                self.WOIDbyWFM)
```

I am getting

> File
>   "C:\Users\OpenSource\eclipse-workspace\PythonWorkSpace\DataHiding\src\Hiding.py", line 26 ^ SyntaxError:unexpected EOF while parsing error

while running the code. please suggest me where i am making errors.

Comment: Add another `)` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have "WOIDbyWFM = {17}\n"..format(self.SNo, .......
You are missing a closing right parentheses at the end of your return statement.

Comment: yes, you were right only a closing bracket was missing Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please use the PyCharm editor and it will show you all errors like eclipse does and then you can correctly indent your code to make it bug free.

Comment: Also I have started using pycharm